# How to pass a value from an input to a submit button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api, use-state

I'm currently working on a project to implement a website to check the weather forecast.

I'm trying to get the value from the input field and when I click the submit button, this value should be set to `cityName`. What do I have to change in order to make this work?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"


export function WeatherInfo() {

    const token: string = '7ebe7c2a03cd48c090a193437'

    async function getCurrentWeather(cityName: string): Promise<any> {
        const response = await fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${token}&q=${cityName}`)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        return data
    }

    const [cityName, setCityName]: any = useState('')
    const [cityWeather, setCityWeather] = useState({})
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const handleChange = (event: any) => {
        setValue(event.target.value)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setCityName(value)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const cityWeather = await getCurrentWeather(cityName)

        }
        fetchData()
    })


    return (
        <div >
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Type here" />
                <button>Search</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a dependency array to your effect hook so that it triggers whenever `cityName` changes.

Updating the `cityWeather` state should *only* be done via the `setCityWeather` function.

```ts
useEffect(() => {
  if (cityName) { // only fetch when you've got a value
    getCurrentWeather(cityName).then(setCityWeather);
  }
}, [cityName]);
```

---

You should also try to use as few `any` types as possible, preferably none

```ts
// define stand-alone functions outside your components
// eg weather-api.ts
const token = "your-api-key";

export interface CurrentWeather {
  temp_c: number;
  feelslike_c: number;
  // etc
}

export async function getCurrentWeather(
  cityName: string
): Promise<CurrentWeather> {
  // safely encode URL query params
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    key: token,
    q: cityName,
  });

  const response = await fetch(
    `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?${params}`
  );

  // don't forget to check for errors
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw response;
  }

  return response.json(); // will be cast to the `CurrentWeather` type
}
```

```tsx
import { useState, useEffect, FormEventHandler } from "react";
import { getCurrentWeather, CurrentWeather } from "./weather-api";

export function WeatherInfo() {
  const [cityName, setCityName] = useState("");
  const [cityWeather, setCityWeather] = useState<CurrentWeather>(); // default undefined
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentWeather(cityName).then(setCityWeather).catch(console.error);
  }, [cityName]);

  const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setCityName(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {cityWeather && (
        <p>
          The current temperature in {cityName} is {cityWeather.temp_c} &deg;C
        </p>
      )}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Type here"
        />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Phil. Your answer was everything I was looking for. Thank you for the explanation as well. About the any type, I'm working on them. I just wanted to make the logic works. Thanks!